# Adding new Object to existing List in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have two classes. First looks like that:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var owner: String?
    var dogs: List<Dogs>()
}
```

and second class which looks like that:

```
class Dogs: Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var age: String?
}
```

and now in `ViewController` in 'viewDidLoad' I create object `Person` with empty `List` and save it in Realm

```
func viewDidLoad(){
    let person = Person()
    person.name = "Tomas"
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(Person.self)
    }
}
```

it works great and I can create `Person`, problem begins when I try to read this data in `SecondViewController` in `ViewDidLoad` doing it:

```
var persons: Results<Person>?

func viewDidLoad(){
    persons = try! realm.allObjects()
}
```

and try to add new `Dog` to `List` doing it in button action:

```
@IBAction func addDog(){
    let newDog = Dogs()
    newDog.name = "Rex"
    newDog.age = "2"

    persons[0].dogs.append(newDog)

    // in this place my application crashed

}
```

Here my app is crashing with an information: `Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.` How can I add new `Dog` to `List` and how can I update person[0]?
I use SWIFT 3.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `persons` property is of type `Results<Person>`, which is a collection containing `Person` objects that are managed by a Realm. In order to modify a property of a managed object, such as appending a new element to a list property, you need to be within a write transaction.

```
try! realm.write {
    persons[0].dogs.append(newDog)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write something like this:

```
if let person = persons?[0] {
    person.dogs.append(newDog)
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true)
}
```

Please check how are you getting `realm`. Each time you call `defaultRealm`, you are getting new realm.

Answer (score 1):

Side Note: Besides adding the code inside the write transaction which solves your issue, you could query `Person` by name as follow...

```
@IBAction func addDog(){
    let newDog = Dogs()
    newDog.name = "Rex"
    newDog.age = "2"

    let personName = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("name = 'Tomas'").first!

    try! realm.write {
        personName.dogs.append(newDog)
    }
}
```